# About transaction using in RSpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, rspec2, database-cleaner

I met a very strange issue when writing test using RSpec. Assume that I have 2 models: Company and Item with association company has_many items. I also set up database_cleaner with strategy transaction. My RSpec version is 2.13.0, database_cleaner version is 1.0.1, rails version is 3.2.15, factory_girl version is 4.2.0. Here is my test:

```
let(:company) { RSpec.configuration.company }
context "has accounts" do
  it "returns true" do
    company.items << FactoryGirl.create(:item)
    company.items.count.should > 0
  end
end
context "does not have accounts" do
  it "returns false" do
    company.items.count.should == 0
  end
end
```

end

I set up an initial company to rspec configuration for using in every test because I don't want to recreate it in every tests because creating a company takes a lot of time(due to its callbacks and validations). The second test fails because item is not cleaned from the database after the first test. I don't understand why. If I change line `company.items << FactoryGirl.create(:item)` to `FactoryGirl.create(:item, company: company)`, the it passes. So can any body explain for me why transaction isn't rollbacked in the first situation. I'm really messed up

Thanks. I really appreciate.

Comment: What's behind `RSpec.configuration.company` ?

Comment: Here is the company setting:

    `RSpec.configuration.company = FactoryGirl.create(:company)`, and I add setting to RSpec by `config.add_setting :company`

Comment: sorry, I don't know to write code in comment...

Comment: you can always edit your question to provide more details

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not in the rollback and I'm wondering if `company.items` can store it's value between `context`s but I'm not sure.

I'm unable to reproduce it quickly so I want to ask you to:

1. check `log/test.log` when the rollback is performed
2. how many `INSERT`s was made for `company.items << FactoryGirl.create(:item)`
3. than change on the first test `>` to `<` that way: `company.items.count.should < 0` it'll make test to fail but you'll get count value. Is it 1 or 2 ?
4. If you have relation between `Company` and `Item` model like `has_many`/`belongs_to` than I would suggest to just use `build(:item)` which should create company for it as well:

for example:

```
let(:item) { FactoryGirl.build(:item) }
context "has accounts"
it "returns true" do
  item.save
  Company.items.count.should == 1
end
```

don't forget to include `association :company` line at `:item`'s factory

**Hint:**

add to `spec_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # most omitted
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
```

and you can call any FactoryGirl method directly like this:

```
let(:item) { build(:item) }
```